# COBOL : Move PIC X TO PIC S9.99 COMP-3

Tags: cobol, mainframe

How I can move data from example :
I-DATA  PIC X7 VALUE '  12.34'.
to
O-DATA PIC S9(13)V99 COMP-3.

Comment: show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Exactly the same way as as noted in my comment at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63393068/cobol-data-type ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cobol data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63393068/cobol-data-type)

Answer (score 1):

```
   05 I-DATA PIC X(7).
   05 I-NUMERIC REDEFINES I-DATA PIC 9999.99.
   .
   .
   MOVE I-NUMERIC TO O-DATA.
```

You need to redefine you AlphaNumerc as a Display Numeric which can then be moved to the packed decimal variable. Be careful as this will bomb out with an OC7 if there is anything other than numbers or spaces plus the '.' in the data.

Answer (score 1):

Your `pic` clause for `i-data` is bad (it should be PIC X(7)).

Anyway to answer your question, use `MOVE ... TO ... WITH CONVERSION ON EXCEPTION ... END-MOVE`

```
05 I-DATA PIC X(7).
05 O-DATA PIC S9(13)V99 COMP-3.
05 HAD-ERROR-FLAG PIC X.
   88  HAD-ERROR VALUE "Y" FALSE "N".
...

MOVE I-DATA TO O-DATA WITH CONVERSION
ON EXCEPTION
  MOVE ZERO TO O-DATA
  SET HAD-ERROR TO TRUE
NOT ON EXCEPTION
  SET HAD-ERROR TO FALSE
END-MOVE
```